# What is the running time?

Tags: big-o

What is the running time (Big-O) of this algorithm? Please help...

```
int digit, sum = 0, count = 0;
while ( n > 0 ){
    digit = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    sum = sum + digit;
    ++count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log n - you keep dividing n by 10, until n has the value 0.

Think about it this way: which variable determines the condition and how is it modified in order to eventually make the condition false?

In this case it's n, and it gets divided by 10 with each iteration. For simplicity, you can think of n as 10^x.